# Holomorphic function question

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm trying to prove that a holomorphic function $f:\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{C}$

That makes $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for any $n\ge1$, and also $f(i)=1$ does not exist.

So far I'm not even sure what theorem should I be using.

Any advise?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: yes that's what i ment

Comment: Do you know the identity theorem-principle?

Comment: yes, but isn't the fact that $\frac{1}{n}\to0$ and $f$ not being defined at 0 is problem in that theorem?

Comment: Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem (15.15), page 298.

Comment: Yes this is a big problem . I am working on it if i have something i will let you know

Comment: This is patently false. Take $(e^{2\pi i/z}-1)/(e^{2\pi}-1)$. It's only true if the function is demanded holomorphic on all of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: oh your right, thank!! :)